# Make formerly encrypted hard drive usable normally again

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, data-recovery

My old laptop died last morning, but the hard drive is still working.

When my brother made the Ubuntu installation, he chose to encrypt the `home` folder. So, whenever I try to use the hard drive on another computer, it asks me about the hard drive pass-phrase. I have already asked my brother about it, and he has no clue about where the old pass-phrase is (it's been 3 years).

**My questions:**

- Is there anyway to clear the hard drive completely or format it in a way that it can be used for another installation?
- In case this is not possible, is there any hardware trick or BIOS trick that I can do to unlock the drive?

**Some useful information:**

If I try the command `sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt/hd2` it gives me the following error:

```
mount: /dev/sdb: can't read superblock
```

If I try to see the partition table using `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` I get:

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdb: Input/output error
```

I can't tell for sure if there was any BIOS level password.

And the `sudo fsck /dev/sdb` command gives the following output:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.28.1
e2fsck 1.43.1 (08-Jun-2016)
fsck.ext2: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to open /dev/sdb
Could this be a zero-length partition?
```

As far as physical problem go, if I plug in the hard drive, there's no problem on it appearing in `/dev`, no clicking noises, and the `dmesg | tail` outputs as follows:

```
[11267.246656] sd 51:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 02 00
[11267.246659] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 2
[11267.246665] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 1, async page read
[11267.265418] sd 51:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[11267.265426] sd 51:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[11267.265431] sd 51:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[11267.265436] sd 51:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 04 00 00 04 00
[11267.265440] blk_update_request: critical medium error, dev sdb, sector 4
[11267.265445] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 2, async page read
[11267.265449] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3, async page read
```

I think that most of these errors are related to the fact that the system can't read the partition table of the device, since it is encrypted.

Finally, there is also a Windows partition in this drive, if that makes any difference.

If there's any need of more information, I'll provide gladly. I also can say that recovering personal data is not my priority in this case, it's more related to being able to use the drive again. Also, I apologize for my English mistakes or improper formating.

**UPDATE 1**

After `dd` finished, I'm facing a weird problem. The disk, that is a 500GB drive, is showing as 2GB, even after formatting it using `gparted`. Also, even after formating it, when I show it in the `gparted` GUI, it shows as below:

[image: Showing on GUI]

[image: Detailed Info of the drive on gparted]

**UPDATE 2**

`dd` reported that wrote 2GB, which I guess was the boot sector or something similar.

`sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb` output:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 1,9 GiB, 1994428416 bytes, 3895368 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

`lsblk /dev/sdb` output:

```
lsblk: /dev/sdb: not a block device
```

`sudo parted /dev/sdb print` output:

```
Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
Model:  (file)                                                            
Disk /dev/sdb: 1994MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:
```

`sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb` output:

```
/dev/sdb:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

The only thing I can guess is that the drive unmounted during `dd` and remounted really quick, that messed up something. Still, I don't know exactly what's going on. Should I try to `dd` it again?

**UPDATE 3**

As requested, `file /dev/sdb` gives me the following output:

```
/dev/sdb: data
```

**UPDATE 4**

I think I may have found something that can be useful in understanding what is happening. Here is a screen shot of `dd` with the drive plugged in:

[image]

And here, after physically unplugging the drive:

[image]

As you can see, there's no error about `/dev/sdb` not existing anymore, and it still list in in ls as you can see in the screen shot below:

[image]

I also noticed this different color that `sdb` appears, it is the same even with the drive plugged in.

As far as I understand, this "ghost" device is the responsible for the `dd` problem, is there any way to get rid of it?

**UPDATE 5**

I used `rm` to delete the "ghost" file, still, I have no clue how it ended up there. Now, if I run `dd`, it does not tell me that it wrote 2GB, and as you can see, after a quick run and interruption, the disk is showing up "correctly" in `gparted`:

[image]

But even so, opening `gparted` is giving me loads of error windows like this:

[image]

Similar windows appear if I try to create a new partition table, or create a new partition in the drive. Does that mean that I have to run `dd` in the entire device or that the drive has physical damage? 
One thing to notice is that I added the option `status=progress` on the `dd` command, and after some time running(not always in the same size) there is no more progress updates, and I'm not sure if `dd` is stuck in a bad sector or something like that. The command I'm using now is `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4M status=progress`.

UPDATE 6

So, `gnome-disks` doesn't give me the option(at least is not enabling) to perform a self test on the drive. Nevertheless, I tried using `gsmartcontrol`, and this is what I got:

[image]

[image]

And if I try performing a self test using this tool, I get this error.

[image]

by using the command line version, running `sudo smartctl /dev/sdb -a` should give me the SMART information, and since the output was quite long, I pasted it on pastebin because I wasn't sure if this post was getting too big.

[command output](http://pastebin.com/Bn4NBdac)

According to the output, there's a lot of errors, but I'm not sure if they are happening because of the encrypted drive problem.

**FINAL UPDATE**

Since there's a BIOS level password active in the drive, and the old computer is dead, there's nothing more to do, except buy a new drive. I'm marking this post as solved. Thanks to everyone who joined and gave toughts about it.

Comment: You can not recover a lost password for encrypted hard drives (except you're the NSA and have lots of time maybe). To make the disk usable again, I suggest to overwrite it with zeroes. This will nuke all data though. Make sure the disk you want to nuke is `/dev/sdb` (else change it in the command!) and then run `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb bs=4M`. This will overwrite everything on `/dev/sdb` and destroy all traces of encrypted partitions etc if the drive is writeable in raw mode.

Comment: How can I verify if the drive is writeable in raw mode? any different command, or should I just `dd`it?

Comment: Just `dd` it. If it works, it works and you'll have a seemingly factory-new disk afterwards on which you can create a partition table and partitions which you can format as whatever file systems you like, e.g. using GParted. Else you have a problem.

Comment: So I should use `dd` in the entire disk, like, wait for it t finish running entirely. Am I right to think that?

Comment: Yup, that's correct. Possibly it could be enough to just overwrite the first few MBs to destroy boot sectors, partition tables and the first file system superblock, but if you are not super impatient, I'd recommend to let it overwrite everything. It might take a while (up to a few hours) though, depending on disk size and speed.

Comment: Thanks, I'm running it, until now there are no errors showing up, I'll update the post after with the results.

Comment: Information Updated

Comment: This is strange. How many bytes did `dd` report to have written? 2GB or 500GB? You can also check the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb`, `lsblk /dev/sdb`, `sudo parted /dev/sdb print` and `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb`

Comment: Information Updated

Comment: Trying the same `dd` command again can not hurt, but this is all very strange and I have no idea why it does not even recognize /dev/sdb as proper hard drive or block device any more. I'm going to search somebody who might know more about this, in the meanwhile you can also add the output of `file /dev/sdb`.

Comment: Requested command output added

Comment: Information updated

Comment: Well, I assumed you have the drive connected when you ran the `dd` command. If you run it while there is no `/dev/sdb` drive present, it just creates a file as large as it can in the virtual `udev` file system mounted at `/dev`.  Make sure that this file is deleted and then connect the drive to access it instead. As there seem to be I/O errors when attempting to write it, I guess on physical damage. Open `gnome-disks` and use it to check the drive's SMART status and run a self test (option can be found in the hamburger menu in the top right corner of the Disks application).

Comment: Information Updated

Comment: This is all very strange, but I'm getting more and more sure that it can not be caused by encrypting the home directory with Ubuntu, but is probably a hardware failure. I think you have to get a new disk, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, whenever I try to use the hard drive on another computer, it asks me about the hard drive passphrase.

Read carefully. Your HDD is encrypted. Maybe your Ubuntu home folder is AS well, but the hard drive itself is encrypted, too. Normally the encryption can be enabled and disabled in BIOS, if you have the password. If you're very unlucky, the drive was encrypted through TPM chips on the old computer, where you won't be able to recover the password anyway. Read the docs of the system, where the hard drive used to be.

That's why smart claims so many errors, every sata command is neglected, because the drive first wants authorization.

Comment: I see, I wasn't sure if there was Firmware level password envolved, Since the computer was never turned off(was like a media center). I'll see if I can find anything about that. Thanks.

Comment: And in the end, there was a BIOS level password, and since the old computer is not working anymore, the only thing to do is buy a new drive. Thanks for appointing that out.